# I want to condition the output with the url. At localhost:3000/admin navbar should should be different

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Navbar should be different in else condition but only if condition is working

```
function navbar() {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.pathname === '/admin') {
    return <section className="text-xl font-GreatVibes">Trrinket</section>;
  } else
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <section className="hidden lg1024:block z-30 mx-8">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <NavBarLinks />
            <NavbarLogo />
            <NavBarControls />
            {/* <NavBarSearch /> */}
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="lg1024:hidden">
          <div className="standalone:h-16">
            <NavBarLogoMobile />
            <NavBarMobile />
          </div>
        </section>
      </Fragment>
    );
}
export default navbar;
```

Different URLs as mentioned

Comment: Does `router.pathname` change?

Comment: Yes it changes but only if condition ( router.pathname === '/admin' ) is rendering not the  else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pathname with react

comapre your page with === includes()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).